# I Cant get Var from Entry in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def func_20_Matrix():

    def func_20_Matrix():
    
    rootMatr = tk.Tk()
    rootMatr.title('Matrix Slove')
    rootMatr.geometry('+550+100')
    
    metrix_Size_X = tk.IntVar()
    metrix_Size_Y = tk.IntVar()
    
    def matrix_Size():
    
        matrix_Solve_root = tk.Tk()
        matrix_Solve_root.title('Matrix Slove')
        matrix_Solve_root.geometry('+600+150')
        
        
        
        print(metrix_Size_X.get(),metrix_Size_Y.get())
        tk.Label(matrix_Solve_root,text='SEE').grid()
        
        matrix_Solve_root.mainloop()

    tk.Label(rootMatr,text='',height=3).grid()
    tk.Label(rootMatr,text='Matrix Calulator',font=('ariel',20,'bold'),justify='center').place(relx=.5,rely=.2,anchor= 'center')

    tk.Label(rootMatr,text='Choose X Matrix : ').grid(row=1,column=0)
    tk.Entry(rootMatr,textvariable=metrix_Size_X,width=6).grid(row=1,column=1)

    tk.Label(rootMatr,text=' x ').grid(row=1,column=2)

    tk.Label(rootMatr,text='Choose Y Matrix : ').grid(row=1,column=3)
    tk.Entry(rootMatr,textvariable=metrix_Size_Y,width=6).grid(row=1,column=4,padx=(0,5))

    tk.Label(rootMatr,text='',height=3).grid()
    tk.Button(rootMatr,text='Complete XY Mateix',command=matrix_Size).place(relx=.5,rely=.8,anchor= 'center')

    root.destroy()
    rootMatr.mainloop()
```

In addition to the code here, there is an additional code that presses the Button, which I don't think is important, so I didn't include it for you to see.

I am making a calculator and I'm still working on the matrix, but now I'm stuck with a problem where the Variable can't receive the value from the Entry.

Now, I've tried to fix it by adding Variables to functions through Lambda, but it still doesn't work as well.

I may have typed it strangely or made it unreadable. I apologize because I used Google Translate.

Comment: Your first function is empty. You need to put come content on it.

Comment: _a problem where the Variable can't receive the value from the Entry_ What variable?  What entry?  We need to know **specifically**.

Comment: The reason why the value is inaccessible is prolly because you are using two instance of `Tk`, you should just use one `Tk` and all additional windows should be `Toplevel` or go for the conventional way of saying `IntVar(master=rootMatr)`, which should also make it work

Comment: Why are you using `mainloop()` twice? One `mainloop()` will do entirely script. The mainloop() will do your job.

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a calculator And I'm still working on the matrix, but now
> I'm stuck with a problem where the Variable can't receive the value
> from the Entry

Your script is fined.

- On `matrix_Size()` function, change this matrix_Solve_root = tk.Tk()
  to `matrix_Solve_root = tk.Toplevel()` # recommend by @Delrius
  Euphoria
- You are missing argument layout manager
  `tk.Label(matrix_Solve_root,text='SEE').grid()` So use `pack()`
  instead of `grid()`.

  Add x and y for  x = metrix_Size_X.get() and  x = metrix_Size_Y.get()
- Comment out this `#matrix_Solve_root.mainloop(`)

Snippet:

```
def matrix_Size():

    matrix_Solve_root = tk.Toplevel() # recommend by @Delrius
    matrix_Solve_root.title('Matrix Slove')
    matrix_Solve_root.geometry('400x400')
    
    
    x = metrix_Size_X.get()
    y = metrix_Size_Y.get()
    print(metrix_Size_X.get(),metrix_Size_Y.get())
    tk.Label(matrix_Solve_root,text='SEE').grid(pady=y, padx=x)
    
   #matrix_Solve_root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot, you can see `Label` moved:

[image]